# Parse string containing numbers into integer array

Tags: c++, arrays, string, parsing

A String is given as an input which consists of numbers and I want to convert it into integer arrays in C++.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

using std::string;
using std::stringstream;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

int main(int argc,char** argv) {

    string num="-24 2 90 24 50 76";

    stringstream stream(num);

    while(stream){
        int n;
        stream>>n;
        cout<<n<<endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output(GCC) :

> -24 2 90 24 50 76 76

Why am i getting extra value and what is the efficient to convert them into integer array ?

UPDATE:

What if the string stream contains delimiter other than space, How to parse this?
For eg:
 `string num="-24,2,90,24,50,76";`

Comment: No, storing in a vector is a good way to get them into something that for all intents and purposes is in array.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The end of file condition is *not* set upon a *succesful* parse, you have to check the state of the stream after parsing.

The second `76` is basically just pure chance. An unsuccesful parse leaves the target operand untouched, and because you did not initialize `n`, it can be anything.

A quickfix:

```
stream>>n;
if (stream)
    cout<<n<<endl;
```

A cleaner fix:

```
int n;
while(stream >> n){
    cout<<n<<endl;
}
```

To store those integers, the canonical way is to use `std::vector` if the number of elements is unknown. An example usage:

```
std::vector<int> values;
int n;
while(stream >> n){
    ...do something with n...
    values.push_back(n);
}
```

However, you can use iterators over streams and use the following:

```
// Use std::vector's range constructor
std::vector<int> values(
     (std::istream_iterator<int>(stream)), // begin
     (std::istream_iterator<int>()));      // end
```

Comment: Actually, the value isn't undefined; for the numeric input conversions, the standard guarantees that the target will not be modified if there is an error.  So he's guaranteed to see the last value read.

Comment: And the important point is that he's using the value without having checked that the input succeeded.  (This is implicit in your code, but it's worth saying explicitly.)

Comment: And finally, if you want a vector of int, the canonical way is: `std::vector<int> values( (std::istream_iterator<int>( stream )),  (std::istream_iterator<int>()) );`.  No loops, no `push_back`; everything happens in the constructor.

Comment: @JamesKanze: But it is undefined because `n` was not initialized; I elaborated a bit on that. Good second third point, glad you reviewed my answer.

Comment: Ah, yes.  Because he defines a new `n` each time around.  I was thinking of something along the lines of `int n; while ( !stream.eof() )` (which we see so often).

Comment: @JamesKanze "the standard guarantees that the target will not be modified if there is an error." Is this also true in C++11?

Comment: @robson3.14 Apparently not.  It looks like this has been changed (which would be a silent change which breaks existing code).  But I think there's a bug in the standard, because there doesn't seem to be any provision for setting `failbit` if there are no characters.

Comment: @djadmin: Better leave your question as what it was: An answered question. Then open a new question (after checking it wasn't answered before) :)

Answer (score 5):

Another means of dealing with a character separated integers list using a vector, which is even perhaps a little more simplistic is more like this:

```
string str = "50,2,25,38,9,16";
vector<int> ints;
stringstream ss(str);
int n;
char ch;

while(ss >> n) {
    if(ss >> ch)
        ints.push_back(n);
    else
        ints.push_back(n);
}
```

that way you can move past any character separations (if they exist) first and then default back to grabbing the integers and adding them to the list if they don't (AKA the end of the list)

Comment: What is with that inner if statement? It's doing the same no matter what?

Answer (score 2):

i don't know if you find the answer for your updated question or not. if you don't you can easily do it by the code

```
for (string::iterator it = num.begin(); it != num.end(); ++it) {
    if (*it == ',') {
        *it = ' ';
    }
    else continue;
}
```

this code removes all your colons and replaces them by space. then you can do just normally