# How do i convert a string to an int array after parsing?

Tags: c++, arrays, string, int

I am trying to convert a string that I have already parsed with spaces into a int array:

```
    //example of string before parsing
    arrElement = "1,2,3";

    //parsing
    for(int i =0; i < size; i++){
        if(arrElements[i] == ','){
            arrElements[i] = ' ';
        }
    }
    //string is now "1 2 3"

    //trying to convert numbers only into int
    stringstream str;
    int intCount = 0;
    int intNum[size];
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        str << arrElements[i];
        if(str == " ") {
        }
        else {
            str >> intNum[intCount];
            intCount++;
        }
    }
```

I am currently getting the result there are five integers reads, instead of the three in the example I made. In addition when I print out the array, I am completely different numbers:

```
    209664128 32764 0 0 0
```

I sort of understand the issue, but I am new c++ so I could be wrong, and I am unsure how to resolve this issue. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: related/dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17724925/parse-string-containing-numbers-into-integer-array

Comment: `int intNum[size];` -- If `size` is a variable (not a constant), then this is not legal C++.  C++ requires constants when specifying the number of entries in an array.

Comment: How would I make it so that the array will exatcly fit the size of the the integers. I can only make an array size so big, then I would have to shorten it eventually.

Comment: @TitustheTitan - `std::vector<int> intNum(size);`

Answer (score 0):

Here are some minimal modifications to make your example working.
I think you should avoid the successive calls between `std::stringstream::operator>>` and `std::stringstream::operator<<`.

```
//example of string before parsing
std::string arrElements = "1,2,3";

//parsing
for(int i =0; i < arrElements.size(); i++){
    if(arrElements[i] == ','){
        arrElements[i] = ' ';
    }
}
//string is now "1 2 3"

//trying to convert numbers only into int
stringstream str(arrElements);
int intCount = 0;
static const int size = 3;
int intNum[size];
for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
    if(str == " ") {
    }
    else {
        str >> intNum[intCount];
        intCount++;
    }
}
```

Comment: I will probably be using that stringstream edit. Thank you!